# Global variable is not working as expected in PHP

Tags: php, global

I'm trying to make my own simple framework in PHP. It's going OK but I'm running into a problem.

I redirect everything back to my index.php, and from there I start loading classes and functions. I split up the url into segments, which works fine, until I want to use the segments in a class.

I have a main controller class like this:

```
class SimpleController {
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        global $uri;
        print_r($uri);
    }
  }
```

It prints out the $uri variable just fine, however when I make a new controller for lets say my homepage, I do this:

```
class home extends SimpleController{

private $template = 'home'; // Define template for this page

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
    
public function index()
{        
    
 
   print_r($uri);
  $view = new View($this->template); // Load the template
     
}}
```

Now it gives me an error, undefined variable. How is this possible, since I made it global in the parent constructor?

Comment: Where did you define `$uri`?

Comment: Its working now, but in my index.php i include a file called routing.php,  thats where i split the url into segments and put them into the $uri array. I have now passed this $uri into the contructor of the parent controller class and its working like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use "global" in PHP..
Just use a public variable in your controller;

New code:

```
abstract class SimpleController {
    public $uri;

    public function __construct($uri)
    {
        $this->uri = $uri;
    }
}

class home extends SimpleController{
    private $template = 'home'; // Define template for this page

    public function index()
    {
        $this->uri; //This is the URI
        $view = new View($this->template); // Load the template
    }
}
```

To create your controller just use:

```
$controller = new home();
$controller->uri = "URI";
$controller->index();
```

EDIT: Removed constructor from home, when you want to use this also pass $uri.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a bad design.
You should not rely on global state. Instead pass $uri in the costructor of your home.

Comment: I would go one further and avoid public member variables. Use getters and setters instead.

Comment: I really want to become a good programmer, could you explain me why i should avoid public variables? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How is this possible, since i made it global in the parent constructor?

It's a new scope, so you have to mark it as global (`global $uri;`) again, if you want to access it.

But it's a bad design, use a member or class variable.

Answer (score 0):

As @yes123 says, your design is very bad, you should avoid the use of global variables. Otherwise, you need to use `global` in every function when you want to use a global variable, change your code to this:

```
public function index()
{
  global $uri;       
  print_r($uri);
  $view = new View($this->template); // Load the template

}
```